# yii2 get values from pust multifield

Tags: post, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have POST request for Yii2

[image]

I need to get values (array) from physiologist_feasters field

```
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

$physiologist_feasters = $post["physiologist_feasters"];
        $user->save(false);

        foreach ($physiologist_feasters as $feaster) {
            $phychologistFeature = PsyhologistFeatures::find()->where(['id' => intval($feaster)])->one();
    
        }
    }
```

I get "invalid argument supplied for foreach()", and in var_dump only last value.

Comment: Set some checks.. if isset..

Comment: Have you declared the inputs as an array? If they all have the same name only the last value will be used. You need to do `<input name="physiologist_feasters[]" />`